# Where do find out what preprocessing the models on tensorflow hub were trained on?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub

I found out that some models available in keras.applications and tensorflow hub have used different preprocessing.
For example I read that the mobilenetv2 model expects images to be scaled [0,1] from tensorflow hub and [-1, 1] in keras.applications.

Now keras.applications models all come with preprocessing functions or at the very least with info on how to preprocess.
Can I look up the same info on tensorflow hub?

I was unfortunately not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

TF Hub relies on the publisher of the model to document what preprocessing if any is supported by the model. A common use of interfaces is encouraged as well (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_signatures), though some publishers may follow their own convention.